# I have a model class in which when price type is "fixed" it return object and when it is "percentage" it return string, I don't know how to it?

Tags: api, android-volley

I have a model which receive a response in which when i have option and furthur values, In values i have a priceType which can be percentage or fixed.
When pricetype is percentage the response is Sting but when price type is fixed the response id object and i receive error..

Accept response

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
product = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(jsonResponse), Product.class);
```

JSON REsponse for Percentage

```
{
                    "id": 73,
                    "option_id": 21,
                    "price": "7.0000",
                    "price_type": "percent",
                    "position": 0,
                    "created_at": "2019-10-22 04:23:16",
                    "updated_at": "2019-10-30 04:57:45",
                    "label": "Red",
                    "translations": [
                        {
                            "id": 73,
                            "option_value_id": 73,
                            "locale": "en",
                            "label": "Red"
                        }
                    ]
                }
```

Json Response for Fixed Price

```
{
                    "id": 74,
                    "option_id": 21,
                    "price": {
                        "amount": "5.0000",
                        "formatted": "$5.00",
                        "currency": "USD"
                    },
                    "price_type": "fixed",
                    "position": 1,
                    "created_at": "2019-10-22 04:23:16",
                    "updated_at": "2019-10-22 04:23:16",
                    "label": "White",
                    "translations": [
                        {
                            "id": 74,
                            "option_value_id": 74,
                            "locale": "en",
                            "label": "White"
                        }
                    ]
                }
```

Price can either be class or String but i don't know how to put in my model class..

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your pojo class like below :--

```
public class Product<T> {
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getOption_id() {
        return option_id;
    }

    public void setOption_id(int option_id) {
        this.option_id = option_id;
    }


    private int id;
   private int option_id;

    public T getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(T price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    T price;

.............
}
```

When response is parsed then you can check the type of the `T` then extract the data in that followed way.

Hope it solves your problem.Let me know if further code required.